# Is there any way I can add/update an object in the internal R package data (`R/sysdata.rda`), albeit inadvisable?

Tags: r, r-package, r-usethis

I have an R package with internal data (by design stored in `R/sysdata.rda`). I would like to update one of the objects in it, or add an object to it.

The `usethis` package has the `use_data()` and `use_data_raw()`, but they do not (and seem to will not) support this possibility (see [`r-lib/usethis#1512`](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/issues/1512) and [`r-lib/usethis#1091`](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/issues/1091)).

How can this still be accomplished? I would like to not interfere with my global (user) environment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#### This answer is just a solution for a specified use case. Whether this is a recommendable workflow is *not* part of this question or answer. I only show how this can be made possible in R.

###### Problem explanation

Per the [`usethis::use_data()` documentation](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/use_data.html), it is indeed not possible to do this, as the `...` must contain "Unquoted names of existing objects to save" (so you cannot add a list with objects) and there is no `add` argument:

```r
use_data(
  ...,
  internal = FALSE,
  overwrite = FALSE,
  compress = "bzip2",
  version = 2,
  ascii = FALSE
)

use_data_raw(name = "DATASET", open = rlang::is_interactive())
```

###### Solution

You can load your current `sysdata.rda` to a separate environment, alter it (by adding of changing objects) and then save it again using `save()` (that `use_date()` actually calls internally):

```r
# create new environment
my_new_env <- new.env()

# load current internal data into this new environment
load("R/sysdata.rda", envir = my_new_env)

# add or replace some objects
my_new_env$dataset123 <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)

# save the environment as internal package data
save(list = names(my_new_env),
     file = "R/sysdata.rda",
     envir = my_new_env)
```

Though for the best portability and lowest space used, you might want to use:

```r
save(list = names(my_new_env),
     file = "R/sysdata.rda",
     ascii = FALSE,
     version = 2,
     compress = "xz",
     envir = my_new_env)
```

Comment: You should definitely not do this: it’s brittle and reproducibility goes out of the window. The data you’re storing in your package should exist, or be regenerated, separately. In other words, the `sysdata.rda` file is a *compiled* version of your externally existing “source” data. `sysdata.rda` should *never* be your canonical source of truth. Deleting `sysdata.rda` from your package should be possible at any time without issues (same as deleting `man`), and regenerating it should be fully automated. — Incidentally, this is *why* ‘usethis’ does not support adding data.

Comment: Something else: setting `hash = FALSE` on `new.env` rarely ever makes sense; use the default (which is `TRUE` for good reason).

Comment: I understand your point. However, (1) please note that this `save()` snippet uses the same code that `usethis::use_data()` uses, and (2) this can be used when a text file in `data-raw` get updated, without the need to manually define all elements existing in `sysdata.rda`. You can have a script to generate the whole file again, or just this script to update a small part. It's the responsibility of the package author to keep the original flow possible as well, not `usethis`'s responsibility.

Comment: Updated the answer with a note, and removed the `hash = FALSE`. Though it would've been nice to hear *why* it's "TRUE for good reason", instead of just stating  this.